# How to automate process of building and submitting applications to AppStore?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

What if i want to make a lot of apps from one? They all will share the same code but have different resources. And i need A LOT of them. So i have to always do the following: build the app, submit it, change the graphics, sounds, xml files, build it, submit it and so on over and over again. Can somebody tell me what is the best way (if there's one) to automate such a process? Tools, scripts, something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can't.

Actually, there may be a way you can, but you **shouldn't**. Uploading so many apps that it is easier to write a script to do it than just doing it by hand means that you are uploading too many apps - if Apple thinks you are flooding the App Store, they will **revoke** your Dev account.